# How to check growth of database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I want to know is there any method to check the growth of database on file

### EXAMPLES

- **Database A** contains all tables in **INNODB** storage engine
- **Database B** contains all tables in **MyISAM** storage engine
- **Database C** contains a mixture of InnoDB and **MyISAM** tables

Answer (score 6):

This is very funny. I just answered a question where I posted queries you can run to tell you how much disk space is consumed by each storage engine by database.

See that post from `Jan 13, 2013` : [Translating backup size to database size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/translating-backup-size-to-database-size/31804#31804)

In essence, you need to consult the information_schema for data and index sizes as viewed by mysqld. Here are some examples of how to get the needed information:

## MyISAM

To get the amount of diskspace used by all your MyISAM tables, run this:

```
SELECT
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,1) myisam_kb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,2) myisam_mb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,3) myisam_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) myisam_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'
    AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
) A;
```

To get this by database

```
SELECT db,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,1) myisam_kb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,2) myisam_mb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,3) myisam_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema db,SUM(data_length+index_length) myisam_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'
    AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
    GROUP BY table_schema
) A;
```

To get this by database and engine

```
SELECT db,engine,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,1) myisam_kb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,2) myisam_mb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,3) myisam_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema db,engine,SUM(data_length+index_length) myisam_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'
    AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
    GROUP BY table_schema,engine
) A;
```

## InnoDB

To get the amount of diskspace used by all your InnoDB tables, run this:

```
SELECT
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,1) innodb_kb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,2) innodb_mb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,3) innodb_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) innodb_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'
) A;
```

To get this by database

```
SELECT db,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,1) innodb_kb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,2) innodb_mb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,3) innodb_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema db,SUM(data_length+index_length) innodb_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'
    GROUP BY table_schema
) A;
```

To get this by database and engine

```
SELECT db,engine,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,1) innodb_kb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,2) innodb_mb,
    innodb_bytes/power(1024,3) innodb_gb
FROM
(
    SELECT table_schema db,engine,
    SUM(data_length+index_length) innodb_bytes
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB'
    GROUP BY table_schema,engine
) A;
```

## CAVEAT #1

I have discussed this many times before

- `Sep 13, 2011` : [Determining max database and table size supported and present size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/determining-max-database-and-table-size-supported-and-present-size/5708#5708)
- `Dec 01, 2011` : [MySQL Workbench Database Sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/mysql-workbench-database-sizes/8662#8662)
- `Jul 07, 2012` : [Find the largest databases on my server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18946/find-the-largest-databases-on-my-server/18952#18952)

## CAVEAT #2

Keep in mind that these queries will report how much actual space is occupied for data and indexes. The actual file sizes may actually be more than the information_schema says. That being the case, you must run `OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;` for each table that has fragmentation.

For example, suppose you have a MyISAM table `mydb.mytable` and you run this query:

```
SELECT
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,1) myisam_kb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,2) myisam_mb,
    myisam_bytes/power(1024,3) myisam_gb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable';
```

Goto to the OS and run on of the following:

- `ls -l mytable.MY[DI]` (Linux)
- `dir mytable.MY*` (Windows)

The sum of the bytes listed may be more than what the information_schema says. If that is the case, go run `OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;` and run the same query, you may notice that the table will shrink.

That being said make sure run periodically run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` against all your tables that experiences heavy updates, delete, and inserts.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I monitor the growth of MySQL table in a dedicated table

The table to keep the values

```
CREATE TABLE `tables_sizes` (
  `table_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `table_size` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `measurement_type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (measurement_type IN ('BYTES','ROWSCOUNT')),
  `measurement_datetime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh

export MYSQL_PWD=XXXXXXXXXX
TABLES="table1 table2 table3"

for TABLE in $TABLES;
do
        FILEPATH=/var/lib/mysql/scarprd_self/$TABLE.ibd
        TABLESIZE=`wc -c $FILEPATH | awk '{print $1}'`
        #Size in Bytes
        mysql -D scarprd_self -e "INSERT INTO tables_sizes (table_name,table_size,measurement_type) VALUES ('$TABLE', '$TABLESIZE', 'BYTES');"
        #Size in rows
        ROWSCOUNT=$(mysql -D scarprd_self -e "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROWSCOUNT FROM $TABLE;")
        ROWSCOUNT=${ROWSCOUNT//ROWSCOUNT/}
        mysql -D scarprd_self -e "INSERT INTO tables_sizes (table_name,table_size,measurement_type) VALUES ('$TABLE', '$ROWSCOUNT', 'ROWSCOUNT');"
        mysql -D scarprd_self -e "DELETE FROM tables_sizes WHERE measurement_datetime < TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY));"
done
```